# woocommerce : update the price of all products priced at 0$

Tags: woocommerce

> how to update the price of 0$ products to 9$ through myphpadmin

thank you guys! Have a great weekend and happy family!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to change the product price from 0 to 9 on simple products in WooCommerce.

```
add_action ('save_post', 'BN_new_price'); 
function BN_new_price( $product ){

    // target price
        $target_price = '0';
    // new price
        $new_price = '9';

    // loop over products
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'           => array('product'),
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => -1,
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        
        if (  $product->is_type('simple') ){
            $active_price  = $product->get_price();
            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
            
        if ($active_price == $target_price) {
              
    //set new price
         update_post_meta($product->id, '_price', (float)$new_price);
        }
        if ($regular_price == $target_price) {
        update_post_meta($product->id, '_regular_price', (float)$new_price);
        }
   }
    endwhile;

    }
}
```

1. add the code to the functions.php file
2. save any product or post to run the code once.
3. dele the code from functions.php as you don't want to run it continuously.